# Не могу редактировать файлы через FTP, созданные с помощью функции file_put_contents

Tags: php

`chown`?

Comment: Наверное, не chown а chmod.

Comment: Права менял руками.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если правильно понял, то нужно заливать файлы через ftp. Тогда вам нужно конектится еще к ftp
более подробно [ТУТ](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.file-put-contents.php#105896)

Comment: если нет, то после file_put_contents выполняйте chmod("file_name",0777);

Answer (score 0):

а еще это может значить что ftp пользователь и php пользователь находятся в разных группах и ftp пользователя нет прав на редактирования файлов созданные php пользователем, если это не VPS то настроить будет проблематично или просите хостера, что бы он решил этот вопрос

Comment: vps, проблема решена